# .remove() is not working properly on .append() jquery except first row

Tags: jquery

In the Code below, It's an invoice management system and one customer could have more than one orders.  The button **Add New Item** works perfectly when adding new rows but when trying to delete it, it's not getting delete until I delete the first row.

Here is the the first row in the table.

```
<tbody id="TableBody">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 220px">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="QTV" min="1" name="QTV" id="QTV" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input step="any" id="Disc" name="Disc" type="number" min="0" name="" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="SubTotal" class="form-control text-right" id="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="DelRow">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the code to append (Add New Row) beneath the old one

```
    $('#AddNewItem').click(function() {
    $('#TableBody').append(`
    <tr>
        <td style='width: 220px'>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='Item' id='Item' placeholder='Nombre del producto' required autocomplete='off'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='number' name='QTV' min='1' name='QTV' id='QTV' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00' required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input step='2' type='number' class='form-control text-right' min='1' id='Rate' placeholder='0.00' readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input step='any' id='Disc' name='Disc' type='number' min='0' name='' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='SubTotal' class='form-control text-right' id='Total' placeholder='Total' readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="DelRow">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    `);
    });
```

Here is the code to delete the current row but it's not working correctly on appended rows.

```
$('#DelRow').click(function(){
    var rowCount = $('#TableBody tr').length;

        $("#TableBody").delegate("#DelRow", "click", function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep2OO.png)

I'll be thankful for contributions.

Comment: you have ID's that aren't unique and are therefore invalid.

Comment: Where is that deleteRow event handler bound?

Comment: Use a `class` for `DelRow`, not an `id`.

Comment: @trincot by using class it has no effect.

Comment: @KevinB that means on every append I have to use unique ID?

Comment: @Muhaddis I mean... that, or don't use ids.

Comment: So what should I @KevinB

Comment: @Muhaddis, using class has an effect. See demo below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `class` to identify the Delete button, because `id` must be unique in HTML:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
```

Then, you should not nest click handlers, just only use the delegation handler you had. Note however that `delegate` is a deprecated method. Use `on` instead (which has the first two arguments reversed):

```
$("#TableBody").on("click", ".DelRow", function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```js
$('#AddNewItem').click(function() {
    $('#TableBody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td style='width: 220px'>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' name='Item' id='Item' placeholder='Nombre del producto' required autocomplete='off'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='number' name='QTV' min='1' name='QTV' id='QTV' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00' required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input step='2' type='number' class='form-control text-right' min='1' id='Rate' placeholder='0.00' readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input step='any' id='Disc' name='Disc' type='number' min='0' name='' class='form-control text-right' placeholder='00'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='SubTotal' class='form-control text-right' id='Total' placeholder='Total' readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger DelRow">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    `);
});


$("#TableBody").on("click", ".DelRow", function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody id="TableBody">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 220px">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Item" id="Item" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required autocomplete="off">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="QTV" min="1" name="QTV" id="QTV" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input step="2" type="number" class="form-control text-right" min="1" id="Rate" placeholder="0.00" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input step="any" id="Disc" name="Disc" type="number" min="0" name="" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="00">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="SubTotal" class="form-control text-right" id="Total" placeholder="Total" readonly>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="DelRow">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="AddNewItem">Add New</button>
```

Comment: Could downvoters please explain why this answer is not useful?